# Writing from MATLAB to Excel with ActiveX

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

I was wondering if there was a way of using the **Cell** function rather than **Range** with MATLAB's ActiveX commands? Perhaps someone has a solution to my problem. I have many lists of data and all of varying sizes, for example:

```
List 1 has 10
List 2 has 13
List 3 has 3
...
```

I would like to take that data and export it to a new sheet in Excel from MATLAB.  I can do it with the **Range** function but this is way too long.  If I had the **Cell** function I would be able to look up the length of `List x` and tell it to loop over the length of the list and move down one cell.

If anyone has another solution I would appreciate the answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I found the solution.  If anyone else is looking for something along these lines this is what I did:

```
i = 10;                              %# in place of the loop index
CellNumber = mat2str(i);             %# convert it to string so that we can append cell letter and cell number
Cell = ['A', CellNumber];            %# append cell number to cell letter to get cell location in excel form
range1 = get(sheet1, 'Range', Cell); %# select specified location
range1.Value = File{i}               %# set that location to what you want
```